# Linguex: gloss alignment with (square) brackets

Tags: brackets, alignment, linguex, gloss

I noticed that linguex aligns the first word of a gloss to the square bracket, and not to the actual word within the bracket.

Here's a part of my document (I copied pasted all the packages I'm using because I have no idea what could influence what in there, I never know):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newclude, relsize, amsmath, amssymb, relsize,xcolor,pifont,setspace, graphicx, stmaryrd, pifont, array, float,xfrac, multicol, tipa, multirow, calc, tabulary, tikz-qtree, bold-extra, color, colortbl, textcomp, anyfontsize, refcount, hyperref}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, dashed=false, natbib=true, uniquename=false, maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false, mincitenames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. A sabe que B tem um bom relacionamento com o rei e a rainha do Marrocos, os quais B visitou umas semanas atrás. \\ 
    A knows that B has a good relationship with the king and queen of Morocco, whom B visited a few weeks ago. 
    \a.[A:] E a rainha, o que ela te deu? \\ `What about the queen, what did she give you?' 
    \b.[B:] Bom, eu não me lembro mais, mas ... \\ `Well, I don't remember, but...'
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    \bg. [o rei]\textsubscript{\textsc{ct}} me deu [um cocar de índio]\textsubscript{\textsc{f}}. \\ 
    the king to.me gave a headdress of Indian\label{rei-ct}\\ `The king gave me an Indian headdress'.

\end{document}
```

Note that in (a), the first word of the gloss *the* aligns with the square bracket, and not with the actual word it correspond to (*o*). The same for the other phrases with square brackets. Is there any work around this?
I understand that some of you think that other packages are better for linguistic examples (expex, gb4e, etc), but if possible I would like to stick to linguex since all my more than 200 examples are already using the commands of this package.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A manual workaround is to put a phantom `[` character before the gloss word. A phantom string is not actually printed in the document, but the width and height that the string would normally use is added at the position of the `\phantom` command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. A sabe que B tem um bom relacionamento com o rei e a rainha do Marrocos, os quais B visitou umas semanas atrás. \\ 
    A knows that B has a good relationship with the king and queen of Morocco, whom B visited a few weeks ago. 
    \a.[A:] E a rainha, o que ela te deu? \\ `What about the queen, what did she give you?' 
    \b.[B:] Bom, eu não me lembro mais, mas ... \\ `Well, I don't remember, but...'
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    \bg. [o rei]\textsubscript{\textsc{ct}} me deu [um cocar de índio]\textsubscript{\textsc{f}}. \\ 
    \phantom{[}the king to.me gave \phantom{[}a headdress of Indian\label{rei-ct}\\ `The king gave me an Indian headdress'.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

You have to use `\phantom{[}` for all words in brackets in all examples, but for 200 examples that seems feasible.